# Why does Perl thinks that `1 and 0` is true?

Tags: perl, boolean

Here is the sample. For some strange reason Perl thinks that `1 and 0` is a true value. Why?

```
$ perl -e '$x = 1 and 0; print $x;'
1
```

Comment: Note that it does give a warning. Unfortunately, it doesn't give the "useless use of ... in void context" error since that warning is suppressed for `0;` (and `1;`).

Comment: Well, it does warning only when running as `perl -we ...` (and the warning is `Found = in conditional, should be == at -e line 1.`). In my example `perl -e ...` I did not get any warning.

Comment: What's your point? You should always use `use strict; use warnings;`. And doubly so if you don't know what's going on. Not to mention check for errors. (Doesn't apply here, but oh so many times people ask what's wrong when they don't even check for errors!)

Comment: My point is that your phrase 'it does give a warning' is incorrect.

Comment: I was talking about the code, not your command. The correct response would be to realize you made a silly mistake by not looking for errors rather than start a pointless thread on whether it gives a warning or not.

Answer (score 12):

Because the precedence of `and` and `&&` differ:

`$x = 1 and 0` is like `($x = 1) and 0`, whereas `$x = 1 && 0` is like `$x = (1 && 0)`.

See [perlop(1)](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.16.2/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity).

Comment: And in particular, the assignment operator (`=`) has a lower precedence than `&&`, but a higher precedence than `and`.

Answer (score 11):

Operator precedence in your example is

```
perl -e '($x = 1) and 0; print $x;'
```

while what you want is:

```
perl -e '$x = (1 and 0); print $x;'
```

or

```
perl -e '$x = 1 && 0; print $x;'
```

Comment: @bessarabov you can accept answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't:

```
$ perl -e '$x = (1 and 0); print $x;'
0
```